# how to prevent two masks from overlapping in pygame?

Tags: python, pygame, collision-detection, python-3.10, pygame2

How would I prevent two masks from overlapping each other when a collision is detected? I know how to detect mask collisions but I can't wrap my head around actually preventing them from colliding. I'm pretty sure the solution has to do something with [`mask.overlap_area`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/mask.html#pygame.mask.Mask.overlap_area), but when I try using the code provided, It doesn't seem to work at all:

[example gif (the blue dot is [dx, dy] )](https://gfycat.com/idolizedvioletgalapagosmockingbird)

```py
import pygame
import sprites

SCREEN_HEIGHT, SCREEN_WIDTH = 800, 800
running = True

pygame.init()

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT))
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

player = sprites.Block((100, 100))
block2 = sprites.Block((100, 100))
blocks = pygame.sprite.Group(block2)

block2.rect.topleft = 150, 150

while running:
    events = pygame.event.get()

    screen.fill((100, 100, 100))
    for event in events:
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False

    player.move(screen.get_rect())
    screen.blit(player.image, player.rect)

    for block in blocks:
        offset = (player.rect.x - block.rect.x, player.rect.y - block.rect.y)

        dx = player.mask.overlap_area(block.mask, (offset[0] + 1, offset[1])) - \
             player.mask.overlap_area(block.mask, (offset[0] - 1, offset[1]))

        dy = player.mask.overlap_area(block.mask, (offset[0], offset[1] + 1)) - \
             player.mask.overlap_area(block.mask, (offset[0], offset[1] - 1))

        screen.blit(block.image, block.rect)
        print(dx, dy)
        pygame.draw.circle(screen, (0, 0, 255), (dx + block.rect.x, dy + block.rect.y), 5)

    clock.tick(144)
    pygame.display.flip()
```

Do I just have the wrong idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the issue is that your program is *allowing* the overlap in the first place.  Once they're colliding you can't do anything.

Before moving the object, check that the destination location is not already occupied by doing a "future collision" check.  If there's going to be a collision, then either don't allow the movement at all, or handle it in some nicer way.

If you know the direction of movement - say the player pushed <kbd>←</kbd>, and is moving left. The code can easily move the player as far left as possible, to the point *just before* colliding.

This way you never have to deal with objects atop each other.

It's not really clear to me what approach the program is taking.  The API [pygame.mask.overlap_area()](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/mask.html#pygame.mask.Mask.overlap_area) returns the *number of bits* overlapping.  The code is calculating the collision normal, not trying to prevent or undo the overlap.  Maybe it can move each object by the inverse of this direction, or suchlike.

Comment: thanks for the information, and I was just trying to see what the different mask methods do in the program and maybe think of something